# Transformation of line $y=k=constant$ under the mapping $w=cos(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, conformal-geometry

I have been going over [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075966/images-of-lines-y-k-mboxconstant-under-the-mapping-w-cos-z) and found myself confused by the calculations given by the OP.
$$\color{red}{ shouldn't \space this \space   be \space   done \space  as \space  follows:}$$

> $$w=\cos z=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{x+iy}+e^{-(x+iy)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))+\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}(\cos(y)-i\sin(y))$$
> $$=\frac{1}{2}\cos(y)\left(e^x+e^{-x}\right)+\frac{i}{2}\sin(y)\left(e^x-e^{-x}\right)$$
> $$=\cosh(x)\cos(y)+i\sin(y)\sinh(x)$$

$$\color{green}{u=\cosh(x)\cos(y)\tag{1}}$$ and $$\color{green}{v=\sinh(x)\sin(y) \tag{2}}$$

> > we are only given constraints for $y$, therefore need to eliminate unknown $x$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$, and this should give us the region $y=k$ transforms to be:

$$\dfrac{u^2}{\cos^2(y)}-\dfrac{v^2}{\sin^2(y)}=\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$$

$$\dfrac{u^2}{\cos^2(k)}-\dfrac{v^2}{\sin^2(k)}=1$$

$$\dfrac{u^2}{\alpha}-\dfrac{v^2}{\beta}=1$$

> > > of which is a $hyperbola$ and not an $ellipse$ as suggested by [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075966/images-of-lines-y-k-mboxconstant-under-the-mapping-w-cos-z)

The quoted post has been giving me headaches and I just didn't know what to do about it.

Comment: The calculations are OK after the first step, but that first step isn't right for cosine. (See answer below.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\cos z$ is not $A=(1/2)(e^z+e^{-z}).$ which you begin with. To see this, imagine $z$ is a real number, then $A=\cosh z.$

Better to start with $\cos z=B=(1/2)(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$ which is correct for real $z.$

Now if one puts $z=x+iy$ we get
$$B=\frac12 e^{i(x+iy)}+e^{i(-x-yi)}$$
which, on multiplying out the exponents and applying the real value formula $e^{ix}=\cos x +i \sin x$ (as itself and also with $-x$ for $x$) the relation becomes after algebra that

$$B=\cos x \cosh y -i \sin x \sinh y.$$
Thus when $y$ is held constant one gets ellipses as in the linked answer.